# ng-if messes up my template really bad

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I`m developing angular app for football scores,
I get the scores and if it`s -1 : -1 ,it means the game is not played yet.
I get a problem when i do the check,ng-if messes up my template pretty badly,It still outputs the values but it does it in places where it shouldnt

here is the code

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days">
<div class="title-link">{{day  | date:'EEEE, MMMM d, y'}} </div>
```

```
    {{game.homeTeamName}}
     <div ng-if="game.result.goalsHomeTeam != '-1'">
      {{game.result.goalsHomeTeam}}
     </div>

    : 
    <div ng-if="game.result.goalsAwayTeam != '-1'">
      {{game.result.goalsAwayTeam}}
     </div>
    {{game.awayTeamName}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by outputs in places where it shouldn't? Please be more specific.

Comment: missing divs are caused by stackoverflow code inserter,dont mind them

Comment: nothing in code shown is problematic...and shouldn't break any html. Sounds like you have some invalid html somewhere like mismatched quotes. Create a sandbox demo that replicates problem

Comment: http://prikachi.com/images/486/8399486t.png see how the score is located  in the date?

Comment: Are you sure you should be comparing the value with the string `'-1'` or the number `-1`? Other than that, as stated above, nothing else looks suspicious and you aren't describing the problem clearly (your pic didn't help).

Comment: what is that picture supposed to show us? Looks fine...but we have nothing to compare to. Create a demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) that replicates the problem

Comment: The output of a game should look like Team A ScoreA : ScoreB Team B,instead it prints the score somewhere else,no idea why.If I replace the ng-if part with a fixed value it works fine.

Comment: Already tried ng-show?

Comment: Yes tried it.The last time we were developing angular app we(again) had a problem with the ng-show directive,now I have problem with ng-if,which I cant figure out .Something tells me there is something messed up with all there conditions

Comment: I would concur with others; this question does not have code in the body that exhibits the behavior being described.  A [mcve] is necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems here that I think you should address correctly.

First, it appears as if you are keeping what should be a Boolean value as a string with the contents being '-1'.

Think of it this way. If I asked you "Was the game played?" and you  responded by saying "dash one!" would that make any sense?

No, it wouldn't because the question you are asking deserves a yes/no or true/false response.

So, first, you should keep a record of whether or not the game was played in a Boolean value that evaluates to true false. You could do this by $watching the score if you want but go ahead and store this value, which has nothing to do with score, as its own value.

It is possible this would solve all of your problems because ng-show/hide/if are all evaluating to true/false anyways.

Second, ng-if documentation states:

Note that when an element is removed using ngIf its scope is destroyed and a new scope is created when the element is restored. The scope created within ngIf inherits from its parent scope using prototypal inheritance. An important implication of this is if ngModel is used within ngIf to bind to a javascript primitive defined in the parent scope. In this case any modifications made to the variable within the child scope will override (hide) the value in the parent scope.

Without actually seeing your code, it is difficult to tell but I think what may be causing your problems is the scope behavior of the ng-if directive.

If you have a jsfiddle or want to screen share I would be happy to help you debug this and explain it.

- Chris

p.s. Here is the source code for ng-if. It is worth looking at to understand what is actually happening.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js#L3

p.p.s understanding childScope/prototypal inheritance.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#javascript-prototypal-inheritance

Comment: 1. '-1' comes directly from the Api,I have nothing to do with the way the person who decided to create it decided to use it.I am ok with his way anywas.The problem is not so much about the score,I can alter the value in the controller if I want to,but I cant figure out why ng-if does not work as described !?

Comment: ng-if does work as described. You should look at the source code. You should also post a fiddle or your code so I can help you further...

Comment: I found out that it will output them incorectly even if there is a only an empty div in the ng repeat,no idea what da *uk is going on?

Comment: describe the desired behavior, describe the actual behavior, isolate the factors leading to the current behavior. Post that code....

Answer (score 0):

You have a cast problem **with -1 and '-1'** you can work around this problem just using `parseInt`.

Comment: This is not the problem.